Problem with savedInstanceState after restarting app
I would like to save a simple integer value beyond the end of an app. I use savedInstanceState for this.
I used the following code in my fragment:
override fun onSaveInstanceState(outState: Bundle) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState)
    outState.putInt("VALUE", value)
}

override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    val currentValue = savedInstanceState?.getInt("VALUE")
    if (currentValue != null) {
        value = currentValue }
}

When I rotate the screen, everything works as desired, the VALUE is saved and retrieved correctly.
But when I close the app and restart it, the savedInstanceState for VALUE is always null.
Do you have an idea what the problem is?

SavedInstanceState is only active during the lifecycle of the app. It's not for saving values that need to be there at restart of an app. You should look into SharedPreferences for that

The savedInstanceState bundle is meant to store data temporarily, primarily to handle configuration changes like screen rotations.
To save data beyond the lifecycle of your app, you typically need to use persistent storage mechanisms such as SharedPreferences, a local database (such as SQLite), or storing data remotely (e.g., on a server).
